# Export from pandas to_excel without row names (index)?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, indexing, export-to-excel

I'm trying to print out a dataframe from pandas into Excel. Here I am using to_excel() functions. However, I found that the 1st column in Excel is the "index",

```
0   6/6/2021 0:00   8/6/2021 0:00
1   4/10/2024 0:00  6/10/2024 0:00
2   4/14/2024 0:00  6/14/2024 0:00
```

Is there any ways to get rid of the first column?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You need to set `index=False` in `to_excel` in order for it to not write the index column out, this semantic is followed in other Pandas IO tools, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Comment: Note that `index=False` does not work if you have MultiIndex columns (as of Pandas 1.3.4, Oct 2021). `NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented.`

Answer (score 52):

Example: index = False

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("dataframe.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = dataframe, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

I did that and got the error message:

TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

The code is as follows where 'test' is a dataframe with no column names

```
test = pd.DataFrame(biglist)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
test.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=test, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: The error occurred for test.to_excel()

Comment: Am using Python 3.8.8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).