# how to prevent the index in a pandas dataframe from showing up in excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (df) which contains some data I would like to output to excel, however I do not want the default index, or any index for that matter being printed to the worksheet.

Is it df.values?

```
df2 
1  |category| num 
2  |A       | 1
3  |A       | 2
4  |B       | 3
```

I want to print to worksheet just:

```
df2 
|category| num 
|A       | 1
|A       | 2
|B       | 3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python to\_excel without row names (index)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089317/python-to-excel-without-row-names-index)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df2.to_excel("filename", index=0)
```

Comment: syntax is the first line on the help page, by default `index=True` is passed. If you explicitly pass it as False then you should not see the index in the output file.

Comment: @yoshiserry you should accept the answer if it worked for you.