# I have a dataframe with values and setting it to a range in excel, how to hide the index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, xlwings

1. I want to hide the index when pasting to this to sheet range

   ```
   sheet.range('B22').values = df
   ```
2. How can I hide the column names (`Data`, `Name`)?

   ```
   print(df)
   ```

   ```
   Index Data  Name
   1      A     X
   2      B     Y
   3      C     Z
   4      D     L
   ```

Comment: Note that you can control index/columns headers individually in xlwings like so: `sheet.range('B22').options(index=False, header=False).value = df`, see: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html#pandas-dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With xlwings use

```
import xlwings as xw
range1=df[['Data','Name']].values
wb = xw.Book('your_file.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
sht.range('B22').value = range1
```

But, in general, using pd.to_excel can be easier. I think this is answered here [[Python to_excel without row names (index)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089317/python-to-excel-without-row-names-index][1]) and also here [[Append existing excel sheet with new dataframe using python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas][2])

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('your_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startrow=21,startcol=1)
```

You can also add, 'header=None', to the to_excel function, if you want to drop 'Data' and 'Name'.

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to past the values in a specific range in an excel using xlwings. I then need to hide the indexes. Or it would be really helpful if we can just hide it from the dataframe

Comment: I edited to include and answer with xlwings. Consider adding xlwings in the description of your question.

Answer (score 2):

When writing a dataframe to Excel, you can do the following to hide both the column names and indices:

```
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: I am using xlwings to achieve this. That is by place my data in specific range. How can i remove index from that range.