# How do I not write the first column to an Excel file using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I use the following code to move data from one Excel file to another.

```
import pandas as pd
inventory = pd.read_excel('Original_File.xlsx', skiprows=3)
inventory.to_excel('New_File.xlsx')
```

How do I NOT write the content in column 1 to the new Excel file? Column 1 contains a blank column header then a row number for each line of data in the dataframe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export from pandas to\_excel without row names (index)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089317/export-from-pandas-to-excel-without-row-names-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

By default, `to_excel` write row names (index) out.

### Solution

when you call `to_excel`, you can skip the row name by setting parameter `index` as `False`:

`inventory.to_excel('New_File.xlsx', index=False)`

### Reference

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html